# Logging repeatable actions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

Working in Python 3.6, I would like to log repeatable actions without excessive number of calls to the logger from within the function's code. Preferably, to have an automated option to spit out a log after every line of code evaluates within a function. Would that be possible?

Below is a minimal reproducible example for something like filtering data:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import logging

# Set up the logger and a dummy data frame
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_A': np.arange(1, 1000, 1),
    'col_B': np.arange(1001, 2000, 1)
})

# Subset rows of the dataframe
logging.info("There are {} rows remaining".format(dummy_df.shape[0]))

# Removing values A below 15
dummy_df = dummy_df.loc[dummy_df['col_A'] > 15]
logging.info("There are {} rows remaining".format(dummy_df.shape[0]))

# Removing values B below 1500 and above 1600
dummy_df = dummy_df.loc[(dummy_df['col_B'] > 1500) & (dummy_df['col_B'] < 1600)]
logging.info("There are {} rows remaining".format(dummy_df.shape[0]))
```

The issue is that I have to write repeatable calls to a logger for what is basically the same operation.

Comment: if you find the call to logging repetitive and "same operation" probably the rest/main code (i.e. not the calls to logging) are also repetitive. In the example you can define a separate function (filtering and logging) that take the df as argument with upper and lower bound as additional params and call that function in a loop

Comment: So... you want to avoid having the same line over and over again...? You can do a function that wraps the previous call, and before returning the value, it does this specific logging thing on the parameter. (Because every time you have `dummy_df=` and every time the logging follows.) Basically `def with_log(df): logging...; return df` and then `dummy_df = with_log(dummy_df.loc[dummy_df['col_A'] > 15])`. This version of `with_log` will work with constructor as well.

Comment: @buran, I do agree that in many cases it's the case, and it's a great shout! However, in my case the conditions are not repeatable in any obvious way, so a loop is not an option.

Comment: alternative would be to define functions for each filter (if they are so different) and call these functions in a loop and single logging statement in the body of the loop. Added benefit - this would be easy to test each function

Comment: @h4z3, another great shout, but for similar reasons as above, I would need to write a separate function for every operation for what essentially is one line of code.

Comment: @buran, so something like a dictionary of filter functions, then loop through the dictionary and incorporate a logging wrapper on top of each function, following h4z3's idea?

Comment: could be a dict, but I don't see need for key, so list/tuple would do. I will post an answer

Comment: Two-line functions are still functions. And it's better to have multiple short functions than one 100-lines function. ;) Such wrapper would be like a decorator (decorators are essentially wrappers for functions or classes) but on function call, rather than function definition. Or rather, in the form I provided, a wrapper for result return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the conditions are so different that it's not possible to have single filter function with changing conditions for the filter.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import logging

# Set up the logger and a dummy data frame
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

dummy_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_A': np.arange(1, 1000, 1),
    'col_B': np.arange(1001, 2000, 1)
})

def filter1(df):
    return df.loc[df['col_A'] > 15]

def filter2(df):
    return df.loc[(df['col_B'] > 1500) & (df['col_B'] < 1600)]

filters = (filter1, filter2)

logging.info("There are {} rows remaining".format(dummy_df.shape[0]))
for my_filter in filters:
    dummy_df = my_filter(dummy_df)
    logging.info("There are {} rows remaining".format(dummy_df.shape[0]))
```

you can add as many filters as you want/need

Comment: I edited my answer, because filter2 was using (by mistake) global variable dummy_df instead of df argument